# disable the current link in a breadcrumb trail

Tags: xslt

Does anyone know how to disable the current link in a breadcrumb trail.

I am working on a bspoke CMS and i have been asked to remove the current link in the breadcrumb trail.

All that i know in XSLT has failed and i have quite some time on, XSLT is no my strength and i need some helpful input. 
Please help

here is the XSLT code:

```
[code]
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!--
    Variable to determine if the current open page is displayed as a link or plain text
    select = 1 - displays plain text link
    select = 0 - displays link (default value)
      -->
    <xsl:variable name="DisableCurrentPageLink" select="0" />

    <xsl:template match="BreadCrumbTrail">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Page" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Page">
    <span class="BCTDelimiter">»</span>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$DisableCurrentPageLink = 1">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@IsOpenPage = 1">
    <span class="breadcrumb-link">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
    </span>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <a href="{@URL}" class="breadcrumb-link" title="{@Title}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
    </a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <a href="{@URL}" class="breadcrumb-link" title="{@Title}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
    </a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>


[/code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard without seeing the input form. That code will make an unlinked span for pages that have `<page IsOpenPage="1">` as the markup, but does you CMS add that attribute for the relevant pages?

If the currently open page is always last in the trail you could change

```
 <xsl:when test="@IsOpenPage = 1">
```

to

```
 <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::Page)">
```

Comment: Hello David Thanks for this, yes the current link is always last in the trail. I made this change but it didn't work by the look of things. here is some html mark up: 



[code]<div id="breadcrumb-outer">
 <div id="breadcrumb-inner">

  <span class="BCTDelimiter">&#187;</span> <a href="" class="breadcrumb-link" title="Home">Home</a> <span class="BCTDelimiter">»</span>
<a href="sample-page/" class="breadcrumb-link" title=" sample page">sample page</a> 
 </div>
</div>
[/code]

Comment: The html markup is the _output_ The XSL you showed is expecting input that looks something like `<BreadCrumbTrail><Page/><Page/></BreadCrumbTrail>` but without knowing exactly what it looks like, hard to fix the XSL...

Comment: Thanks David, what exactly do you need?

Comment: The bit of the input to that xslt that looks like `<BreadCrumbTrail>...</BreadCrumbTrail>`

Comment: Thats the bit i cant find, and i thought it was the html, . . . . . . . . let me think. thanks for this David, all said and done you have helped.

Comment: Sorry i need the link removed not disabled

Comment: well that's easy: just comment out this bit   `<span class="breadcrumb-link">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
    </span>`